# Scripts and CSS files that are not being used

Tags: vue.js, lazy-loading, vuetify.js, nuxt.js

So, I have a vue application with Nuxt/Vuetify/Vue-router and recently I've been doing a little research about lazy load this files that are not being used: [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Du3GM.png)

My question is how can I lazy load them since vuetify and nuxt are generating this files and I can't modify them.

Comment: I am not sure, what exactly happens but two things:
1. Why would you want to load a file at all if it is not used? and 2. `.sass` is never directly read by the browser. Webpack should transpile it into `css` and use that...

Comment: Other than that, it is indeed difficult to lazyload small fragments of your application. BUT: you could lazyload some components, for example with https://github.com/hilongjw/vue-lazyload#lazy-component. Have never tried lazyloading components, but using this plugin for images is alright.

Comment: For the first thing they are all being used just not 100% as you can see the % in unused bytes. For the second thing I don't know if it is the components that I made that it's causing this, because there's this generated files like fonts and one signal that we import through CDN and the nuxt generated files too that I can't edit (I think). So, I'm really new at this and didn't post any code because this is more a conceitual question, just trying to understand how this process should work

Comment: Well in general nuxt is bundling all your code for your app in several files,for example your app.js. (btw: I don't understand everything either, I am just trying to pass on, what I've learned so far while using nuxt).
When you open a page with your component, your app.js  contains more than only that component, ending up in an app.js that has unused code. It does not mean your app.js has code that is never used (at least I hope so :))
Concerning your sass file. I just checked a production build of ours and I did not see any sass file present...

Comment: Maybe this is because your a locally in dev mode and it has to do some extra stuff with browsersync etc.? Maybe for your sourcemaps as well? Not sure. Just check if your production build also shows a sass file...

I also just realize that the biggest part of unused stuff is in your vendors file. That also makes pretty much sense. Let's assume you load a third party plugin, which has to be bundled and shipped. Not all of your pages and components will use those plugins-> unused code.

Comment: Sometimes if you don't pay attention you ship too much (e.g. with moment.js you ship additional locale files which are all included in the vendors.app.js) That is why I would use `--analyze` when building your app. This will open up a nice view to see what is inside your vendors part, and maybe you can spot something that is too big, or should not be there...
cheers

Comment: So, our production build does'nt show any .sass file but it still show 3 nuxt files, 2 fonts and one signal that are imported through CDN, are not being 100% used, so my question still remains

Comment: As I said: Your app includes all your JS in those files. When you move to your index page, maybe 50% of the bytes are used. If you keep on navigating through your page, you should be able to see the green bars rising, because you encounter more and more components, which means more of your code is used.
Also maybe your app already includes some data of your pages. So even navigating between your pages could make the green bar bigger.
I just tried that with a nuxt page of ours.

Comment: Although I have to admit that I never reach a 100% green bar. But I assume that some code is maybe still necessary, maybe the coverage also only shows the code that is used on the client. ‍♂️
Maybe write a question within the nuxt github repository and ask this. I would be interested in the final answer as well.

Comment: Also you can just open that file that is not covered like shown in this screenshot here: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/coverage/
and see which parts are never used (red). Then you might get a feeling what the unused parts are...
In my case I see a lot of red code for if/else statements (only one is green), code that is executed on form submission, etc. I am pretty sure that you never reach 100%, except if you have an extremly simple page, which does not need checking some conditions and always just does one thing in a single way.